# Support Setting in Salesforce - How to use System User details

Tags: actionsupport, email2case, web-to-case

In my `Salesforce` org, there are many channels through which you can create the case like `Web-To-Case`, `Email-to-Case` etc. When the case is getting created by any channel `Case Notification` is going to the User whose Account is configured in the Case Creation.

When email is going, it's going from `Personal/Business EmailId` of one of the `User`. Because it looks like it taking details configured in the **Support Setting.** As such we've not configured his/her details in Support Setting.

I would like for each channel Email Notification/Acknowledgement should go from **no-reply@abc.supportteam.com** or from the System Users. How can I do that?

Do I need to create some Dummy User/System User to configured in the Support Setting ?

Comment: Any help on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, you have configured Auto response rule for email-to-case or web-to-case generation.

In the auto response email id you can specify Organization wide email address or email address of Salesforce user profile.

If email needs to show domain address (like `reply@abc.supportteam.com`) then you need to [setup Email Relays](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_relay.htm&language=en&type=0).

> Email Relays

- Route all email from Salesforce through their own email servers. This prevents the appearance of email spoofing by Salesforce. Email spoofing is the forging of email headers to make messages appear as if they came from someone other than the original sender.
- Store copies of all email as required by government regulations in various industries.
- Apply existing content filters that scan messages for data and content that is not approved to be sent out through company email.
- Run outbound email through antivirus software before sending it to customers.
- Append data such as company-wide disclaimers at the bottom of email messages.

If email needs to show System user's email then create a system user and provide that email id as auto response email id.

Also, I could recommend to use same System User as `Automated Case User` in Support Settings.

From [Customize Support Settings documentation about Automated Case User](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_supportrules.htm&type=0)

> The user listed in the Case Feed feed items and Case History related list for automated case changes. Automated case changes can occur from assignment rules, escalation rules, On-Demand Email-to-Case, or cases logged in the Self-Service portal. You can:
>
> Select User to use the lookup field to specify a user, such as an administrator, to be the Automated Case User. This user must have the System Administrator profile or the “Modify All Data” and “Send Email” permissions.

Comment: No, I have not configured the Auto Response etc. The notifications are going from "Auto-Response Email Settings". What if we create a User in SFDC system and created domain email Id for that Account, it will help with minimum changes. Right? What you says?

Comment: Yes, that's good